# How to lookup value from one table to another in Azure Data Explorer (kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I’m newbie in Kusto language but experienced in SQL. So maybe I’m doing things in completely wrong way.

I’m trying to create query which needs to check if value from one table exist in another.

Something like this:

```
let T1 = datatable(id: int, ss:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic(["qwe", "rty"]),
    2, dynamic(["uio", "pas"]),
    3, dynamic(["dfg", "hjk"]),
];
let T2 = datatable(id:int, s:string)
[
    1, "rty",
    2, "abc",
    3, "hjk"
];
T2
| join (T1) on id
| extend e=case(s has_any (ss),"Yes","No");
```

But getting error “Error has_any(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant”.

Is there way to do it?

Even better with function, something like this:

```
let E = (i_id: int, i_s: string)
{
T1 | where id==i_id | project e=case(i_s has_any (ss),"Yes","No")
};
T2
| extend e=E(id,s);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are a couple of options for you to consider:

1.

```
let T1 = datatable(id: int, ss:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic(["qwe", "rty"]),
    2, dynamic(["uio", "pas"]),
    3, dynamic(["dfg", "hjk"]),
]
;
let T2 = datatable(id:int, s:string)
[
    1, "rty",
    2, "abc",
    3, "hjk"
]
;
T2
| join (T1 | mv-expand ss to typeof(string)) on id
| summarize e = case(countif(s == ss) > 0, "Yes", "No") by id, s
```

2.

```
let T1 = datatable(id: int, ss:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic(["qwe", "rty"]),
    2, dynamic(["uio", "pas"]),
    3, dynamic(["dfg", "hjk"]),
]
;
let T2 = datatable(id:int, s:string)
[
    1, "rty",
    2, "abc",
    3, "hjk"
]
;
T2
| join T1 on id
| project id, s, e = case(indexof(tostring(ss), s) > 0, "Yes", "No")
// not necessarily accurate, depending on the values in the actual data
```